# how to select particular element from following matrix?(in matlab)

Tags: matlab

```
data = rand(N,2);             %# generate random points
index = (rand(N,1) <= p);     %# roll coins to pick with prob p
data(~index, :) = [];         %# keep only selected points
plot(x(index),y(index),'r*');

dist=sqrt((data(1,1)-data(~index,1))^2+(data(1,2)-data(~index,2))^2); % ques is what to put for data(~index,:) 's first or any element?
```

If we have to find distance between any point of `data=rand(N,2)` (say first) from any point of `data(~index, :) = [];` (say first of this also), how can we use `data(~index, :) = [];` matrix in following statement?

```
dist=sqrt((data(1,1)-data(~index,1))^2+(data(1,2)-data(~index,2))^2)
```

My question is as we are taking first element of `data` as `data(1,1)` and `data (1,2)`, how do we take take first element of `data(~index,:)` matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want to do.

The command `data(~index, :) = []` removes all rows for which the random number is larger than p, so after that command `data` will no longer be an N-by-2 matrix but it will be a smaller matrix. I'll assume you won't give that command, because afterwards you can no longer refer to the points in `data` that were removed.

If you want to take the distance between the first point in `data` and the first point in `data` selected by the random coin throw, one possibility is to use the `find` function (look it up to see what it does):

```
indexList = find(index);
firstIndex = indexList(1);
dist = sqrt((data(1,1)-data(firstIndex,1))^2 + (data(1,2)-data(firstIndex,2))^2);
```

The last line can also be written as:

```
dist = norm(data(1,:) - data(firstIndex,:));
```

If you want something else, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you by 'first element of *data(~index,:)*' you mean the first element for which *~index* is true then the following would also work

```
firstValue = data(find(~index,1,'first'),:)
```